# $f,g\in L^1(\mu)\implies fg\in L^1(\mu)$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and suppose that $f,g\in L^1(\mu)$, i.e.
$$\|f\|_1=\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\|g\|_1=\int_X|g|d\mu<\infty.$$
How to show that $fg\in L^1(\mu)$?

**Attempt:** I know how to prove that
$$\|fg\|_1 \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q$$
for any $1<p,q<\infty$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and for $p=1,q=\infty$ and $p=\infty,q=1$. But can we use this to prove that $\|fg\|<\infty$? So we have, for example
$$\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_\infty,$$
and $\|f\|_1<\infty$, but I don't think we can say $\|g\|_\infty<\infty$ so this doesn't show anything.

Comment: This is in general not correct. Take the measure space $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and $f=g$ defined as $f(x) = x^{-3/4}$.

Comment: What about $X=(0,1)$ and $f:t\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ ? $f\in L^1(X)$ but $f^2$ is not.

Comment: One of these guys should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show $fg\in L^1(\mu)$ because it is not true in general. Let $X = (0, \pi/2)$ and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $X$. If $f(x) = \sqrt{\sec(x)}$, then $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$ but $f^2\notin L^1(X,\mu)$.

Comment: No, $L^1(\mathbb N)$ constist of the *absolutely convergent* series.  So this is not a counterexample.  In cases like counting measure, we have $L^1 \subset L^\infty$, so $\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_\infty$ will finish the proof in this case.